# find files belonging to a user with size in mb on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am using this command which is working fine

```
sudo find / -user web132 -ls
```

but when I am trying like

```
sudo find / -user web132 -ls -lh
```

I am getting the wrong syntax error.
How can I get the file sizes belonging to a user in MB.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do:

```
sudo find / -user web132 -size 125M
```

This will give you all files belonging to the user of this given size

Or:

```
sudo find / -user USER -exec ls -lhd $PWD/{} \;
```

That will return every single file belonging to the user, detailing the absolute path and the size

Comment: No I want to list all the files with size in MB.

Comment: ls -aRlh / | grep user

Comment: @LuisSieira That is a good one but you can do better by using a regex to place the user name in the 2nd and/or 3rd column so that only the ownerships are matched but not the filenames.

Comment: a better one, so good that I will post it as an answer:

 find . -user USER -exec ls -lhd $PWD/{} \;

It avoids the possible mismatch username/groupname/filename with grep